# Jquery - .prop not checking my input checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple data table where I added checkboxes that you can select. I have an edit button that would show the details of the data. I have it set so that everytime you hit edit it will pull the data from ajax and fill it's fields and checkboxes accordingly.

The issue I have is mainly with the checkboxes. At the moment my saving functionality is working great. I use the below code to determine if the checkboxes is checked or not and returns true or false in my database.

```
Candidat_gestion_de_problème: $("#Candidat_gestion_de_problème").prop( "checked" )
```

The issue is with the following code, when I hit edit button it pulls its data from the database:

```
$("#Candidat_gestion_de_problème").prop( "checked", incident.Candidat_gestion_de_problème );
```

Note: incident.Candidat_gestion_de_problème returns with `true` or `false`. I had them tested in my console and it is exactly what it spitting out.

In some cases even if the database returns false, .prop seems to ignore and leaves the checkbox checked.

When I perform the same code manually in the console it works fine:

```
$("#Candidat_gestion_de_problème").prop( "checked", false );
```

Would anyone understand why it would do this?

Comment: do you have multiple checkboxes with the same id

Comment: No just testing with a single checkbox

Comment: can you try $("#Candidat_gestion_de_problème").prop( "checked", incident.Candidat_gestion_de_problème  == true ? true : false);

Comment: Dosen't seem to making a difference. No errors either on the console.

Comment: Im doing this within a success call at the moment via ajax.

Comment: Ill try working ona  jsfiddle, but I did put a console.log in my success calls to see what I was getting back from the database and I am getting true and false as expected. Just can't understand why .prop isnt picking that up.

Comment: Did a quick test on my success call and $("#Candidat_gestion_de_problème").length returns a 1. So it does seems to pickup the dom. The checkbox is not added dynamically. It's sits in a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Well SadiRubaiyet had an interessting aproach but tweaked it just slighty and it worked:

```
$("#Candidat_gestion_de_problème").prop( "checked", incident.Candidat_gestion_de_problème == "true" ? true : false );
```

I was hoping to avoid this method but don't see a way around this at the moment. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Oh so you werent using the actual boolean primitives true/false but a string representation. That was the problem non-empty strings are truthy which is why when the value was `"false"` it stayed checked

Comment: yeah it's weird, I was expecting it to return the boolean primitives true/false values. But with the way I have it setup it dosen't seem to like that. But its fine for now.

Comment: You don't need the ternary operator. Just use `.prop(checked, incident.Candidat_gestion_de_problème == "true")`

Comment: It would probably be better to change the code that sets `incident.Candidat_gestion_de_problème`, so it sets it to a boolean instead of a string.